# Simple question about slicing and for loops without indices

Tags: python

If I was making this loop:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
  for j in range(len(array)+1):
    # some code using array[i] and array[j]
```

Would there be a way to do the same thing in this format?

```
for element in array:
  for next_element in array:
    # some code using element and next_element
```

Or would I just be better off using the `i, j` format?

Comment: What you mean by "better"?

Comment: Why does the second loop use `len(array)+1`? The last `array[j]` will be outside the list.

Comment: It's a matter of personal style, but I generally recommend using `for element in list:` whenever you don't actually need the indexes. And if you need the indexes, use `for index, element in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Where is ***slicing*** in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
for element in array:
    for next_element in array[1:]:
        # some code using elemnt
```

I guess it all depends on your end goal or personal preference. What I did here is start our second loop from the second value towards the end. If you need the indexes, you can use `enumerate()` like this:

```
for index_a, element in enumerate(array):
    for index_b, next_element in enumerate(array[1:]):
        # some code using the elements and the indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in array:
  for next_element in array[1:]:
    # some code using element and next_element
```

Please note that your first loop will throw an index error because j goes out of bounds on the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The i and the j could be anything you want it to be, inside the for loop it's going to mean the same thing. Hopefully I understood your question correctly.